# resize label text in Windows application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

how to resize lable text form2 at run time in C# windows application?.. for example if click button in form1 to open form2 then how to change form2 label text  at run time...normaly form2 label text "saran" but if you can click form1 button1 click automatically change to "SARAN"
Example code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    form2.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will either have to make the modifier public of the Textbox on form2 or you will have to create a method in form2 that will change the text on the form.

Something like

**Example 1: textbox modifier is public**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    form2.myTextBox.Text = "TADA";
    form2.Show();
}
```

**Example 2: public method on form2**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    form2.SetMyTextBox("TADA");
    form2.Show();
}
```